# Manifest V3 and using WebRequest with Enterprise Policy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

We have an extension developed for internal use that uses WebRequest API. The extension is installed using "ExtensionInstallForcelist." Based on various documentation, it seems like we would be able to continue to use WebRequest API but there are parts that are still unclear.

1. The timeline on https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/ states that "January 2024 - Manifest V2 enterprise policy expires."

   - Does this mean that starting January 2024, Chrome will stop running Manifest V2 extensions, even the one that is installed using "ExtensionInstallForcelist"?
2. [This article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#when-use-blocking-webrequest) says "public" extension is one that is published to the webstore. Does that definition also apply to "unlisted" extensions? Right now, we perform initial install from our server using "ExtensionInstallForcelist" but update from the webstore having the extension unlisted.
3. The reason why we update from webstore was because updates used to be only allowed from the webstore. (We may have missed something) But it looks like starting from version 89, there was an option introduced that would allow updates from outside of the webstore. The option is "override_update_url" in [ExtensionSettings](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9867568?_ga=2.176262437.1841400016.1668025214-1641697613.1667508280&visit_id=638036220444575985-611263652&p=Configure_ExtensionSettings_policy&rd=1). Does anyone have experience with this option?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Unlisted is still published, that second phrase can be ignored, only the first one is meaningful. 3) IIRC there's a way to run your own web store for enterprises.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your response! Is there an article with instructions on how to setup our own web store? Is it just matter of hosting the CRX on a web server or is there more official setup? During our initial research 5-6 years ago, we couldn't find such information and everything was stating that we must update from Chrome WebStore.

Comment: I don't know. Try looking again now, or ask for official support in the [extensions group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions).

Comment: @wOxxOm Okay, will do that. We were testing the V3 with WebRequest and it fails to load when we try to load it in developer mode. Is this expected? Even for testing, we will need to use force install option, if the extension user WebRequest?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1338871. You can overcome it by using Chrome-Developer-Mode-Extension-Warning-Patcher in Windows.

Comment: Here's instructions for [managing extensions in your enterprise](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9296680?hl=en)